# Is it possible to set the UITextField deleage and set its delegate as itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uitextfield

I am trying to create a self contained customised `UITextField` class who's main responsibility would be to turn text into `Tokens` the same way `NSTokenField` works on Mac OS X. This way if someone requires a Tokens like textfield they would just instantiate an instance of uitextfield and have it subclass my class.

**My question is about delegate control.**

The goal is that I'm trying to receive the textfield delegate methods for when a user interacts with my custom textfield. How can I do this without passing the delegate to anyone else.

Or do I have to observe for notifications instead?

This is what I have done so far in an attempt to make a self contained class:

```
//PKTokenTextField.h
@interface PKTokenTextField : UITextField<UITextFieldDelegate>


//PkTokenTextField.m
```

And in the `.m` file I have:

```
#import "PKTokenTextField.h"

@implementation PKTokenTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        [self commonSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

-(void)commonSetup{
    self.delegate = self;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"description field did become responder");
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSLog(@"LOL OF COURSE");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this if you want. As long as a class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, it can be set as the text field's delegate, even if it's the text field itself.

However, this defeats the purpose of delegation, which is to allow one object to coordinate with, change, and react to changes in another object, while minimizing coupling between the two.

If you can achieve the effect you're looking for through subclassing, composition, or modifying the text field's properties, you should do that instead. (Note that `NSTokenField`, the example in your question, doesn't need to override the delegate.)

See also: [`TITokenField`](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenField).

Comment: I have seen TITokenField, although im not particularly happy with the result of the end product. It doesn't work in the way you can interact with the tokens as you can on OS X. 

All im trying to do is get my custom textfield to respond to itself so that it can pick up the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and other UITextFieldDelegate protocol methods.